# author not appearing in \maketitle in amsart

Tags: titles, amsart

I am new to the `amsart` document class. For some reasons \author (etc..) is not showing after I use `\maketitle`. This is my tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{latexsym} 
\usepackage{pictexwd}
\usepackage{pdftricks}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}

\begin{document}

\title{Temptation, Asymmetric information and Committment}

\author{Mark}

\affil{University of Leicester}

\date{February 2014}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
To be written
\end{abstract}

\section{introduction}

...

\end{document}
```

and this is the output:
[image]

can anybody help me out?

Comment: Ok, I have used package \usepackage{titling} and at least I get everything but I am sure there has to be some other way...

Comment: Your MWE is overly complicated many irrelevant packages. Doesn't `amsart` have its own system for authors and their affils?

Comment: I Apologise (this is actually the first time Ihear about minimal working examples) I will do better next time.

Answer (score 7):

the way author information is handled by `amsart` is quite different from how it is
handled by `article`, and the `authblk` package is based on the `article` conventions.
this difference is what is causing the author information to be omitted.

if you really need the authors presented as they are in `article` (modified by `authblk`),
then `amsart` is not going to work for you.

if you are willing to accept the `amsart` presentation, then you will also need to
change `\affil` to `\address` or `\curraddr`.  also, the facilities of `amsthm` are
built into `amsart`, and `amsmath` and `amsfonts` are automatically loaded, so it's not
necessary to specify those three packages with `\usepackage`.

Comment: Hello. Yes I know about amsmath and the others. Honestly I keep them there not to forget them for when I use the article document class. Can this create any conflict?
As for the author issue. I am not sure I need the same output of article. I wondered if there is a way, any way, to have the authors presented in amsart as well. Not necessarily as in article (actually I do not like the article class that's why I am trying to move to amsart...)

Comment: the ams document classes protect against "double loading" of these packages.  however, if you want to apply some option to one of the packages, it will be ignored if added with `\usepackage`.

Comment: regarding author information, changing this to the style used for `article` would only be possible by completely redefining how the information is handled on input. that would be a major modification to the internal code of `amsart.cls`. there *is* one journal based on `amsart` with a more `article`-like topmatter block: the *quarterly of applied mathematics*; get the [author package here](http://www.ams.org/publications/journals/journalsframework/qamauthorpac).  it should be easier to modify that than to start from `amsart.cls` itself.  (please remove any ams support info if you do so.)

Comment: I see. Thank you I will look into the package and correct this as soon as I can.