# why my authors and addresses do not show?

Tags: front-matter

Here is my node, anything wrong? But my authors and addresses do not show. Thanks.

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,english]{amsart}

\usepackage{authblk}

\@ifundefined{showcaptionsetup}{}{%
 \PassOptionsToPackage{caption=false}{subfig}}
\usepackage{subfig}
\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
%\usepackage{csquotes}
%\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
%\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\title{Forming Competitively Balanced Teams}

\author[1]{ABC}
\author[2]{DEF}

\affil[1]{School1 \\
Email: abc@school1.edu}
\affil[2]{School2\\
Email: def@school2.edu \\
}

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
adfadf
\end{abstract}

\section{aaa}
\section{bbb}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess your code will not compile ;-) Include `\makeatletter` before `\@ifundefined` please

Comment: the basic answer is that `amsart` treats the top matter differently from other article classes.  see some details here: [author not appearing in `\maketitle` in `amsart`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155788/579)

Comment: @cslstr Too fast. Give some time for the OP to react