# Remove Oxford comma from author list in amsart

Tags: punctuation, amsart, authblk

By default, in `amsart` multiple authors are listed with an Oxford comma. The comma cannot be removed using the `authblk` package, since the latter is poorly compatible with `amsart` (as discussed in answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155788/77849).

Question: how can it be removed?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\title{Title}
\author{A}
\author{B}
\author{C}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\makeatletter
\def\author@andify{%
  \nxandlist {\unskip ,\penalty-1 \space\ignorespaces}%
    {\unskip {} \@@and~}%
    {\unskip \penalty-2 \space \@@and~}%
}
\makeatother
\title{Title}
\author{A}
\author{B}
\author{C}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: maybe use `\renewcommand` rather than `\def`?  (but that is certainly the correct expansion.)